Can't get past sddm after upgrade to 24.04
Just upgraded to 24.04. System is old (Pentium) but no graphics card bs to deal with, it's all intel. System boots fine but after password is entered it won't get out of the login manager and into the desktop.
This person seems to have had luck with booting through recovery mode first (but doing nothing in particular in it) but I haven't. The only difference that makes is that I'm greeted with a black screen after the password is entered but the desktop won't load.
In a tty I logged in and looked at top, there are no kde processes. It's as if nothing is being loaded past sddm.

I don't see how the link you provided relates; kubuntu-installer-prompt is not related to sddm and the question you link appears to me to be related to issues using apps on a running KDE Plasma system, where as sddm runs before a session (or KDE Plasma) is even started. Do you have sufficient space in $HOME (your user directory), as the KDE plasma session will abend & return you to sddm if it cannot start due to lack of space..   Text logins will work however with limited space; allowing you to fix it (just not GUI sessions that need space)

The link is relevant bc of the second issue related there, and the person seems to have had luck with that one... Anyway, yes, there is enough space :/

In the end, I found it easier to connect the computer to the internet (via cable), switch to a tty (Ctrl+Alt+F3), login, and install plasma-workspace-wayland:
sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland

It didn't exactly fix what was wrong with the system as it was but instead provided a new way to make it work again. Restart the login manager:
sudo service sddm stop
sudo service sddm start

Choose "wayland" in the menu at the bottom of the screen, that's it.

I posted this on Reddit as well and a user seems to have come up with another possible way to solve this - without installing / having to use Wayland:
This is what they wrote:
"I'm running this on a Surface Go and have maliit-keyboard installed. That's causing the hang in X11 sessions, you can see an error message in the xsession-errors.log indicating that the parameters are incorrect for the command. What it doesn't tell you is that it's not running in the background, so I think the login is "hanging" because starting maliit-keyboard never returns. I changed the startup to put maliit-keyboard in the background and now my login will proceed"
I'm not sure how you would change the startup, although putting maliit-keyboard in the background probably entails adding a '&' to the end of the command.
This is likely the source of my woe too cause the system this problem existed in was a touchscreen device with maliit-keyboard installed as well. I won't be trying this since I'm happy with wayland and it's the future, might as well start using now, but this can be a proper solution to those who need X, especially for gaming as was this user's case.
